# App doesn't auto-start an app when booting the device in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, startup

I have managed to implement the following method coding that allows the app to perform an auto-launch when the device is booted/started-up. However, when I tested out the implementation code, it failed to work, the app has failed to perform an auto-launch when the device is booted. Can anyone please help or advice me what could be the possibilities? Thank you.

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
</uses-permission>

<receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"
          android:name="com.dapoaugury.apps.robotapp.AutoStartUp"
          android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
          android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

AutoStartup.java

```
package com.dapoaugury.apps.robotapp;


/**
  * To Auto-Start Application on Device Start-up/ Boot
  * Created by dev02 on 10/7/15.
 */
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AutoStartUp extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            //To start new intent when phone starts up
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            // To put activity on the top of the stack since activity is launched from context outside activity
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            // EDITED
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
        //To Start Application on Phone Start-up - 10/7/2015(END OF VERSION)
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java (Mechanism that is suppose to be manually launch when app is first installed)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


public static long AppElapsedTime;
public static long AppElapseTime_hr;
public static long Process_startTime = System.nanoTime();
public static long CurrentProcTime;
private static Context context;

public final static int GREEN = 0;
public final static int BLUE = 1;

private static int cTheme = GREEN;

WebView webView;
ProgressBar pb;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...........
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A newly installed app is placed in a "stopped" state until the app is actually launched for the first time. In this state none of your components will be activated, so your `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver will not run. You need to include an activity and have it be opened by the user; you can always disable the Activity using `PackageManager` later.

This behavior was introduced in Android 3.1, you can read about it [in the release notes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html) (under the heading "Launch controls on stopped applications").

Comment: I dont really get your meaning. Hence, how should I enable the app to "escape" the "stopped" state to allow it to be launched when the device is booted

Comment: So does this mean that i will have to add the following code `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);` within the `onReceive()` method?

Comment: That is a flag of the intent that is broadcast. You are not sending the broadcast, therefore you cannot add that flag to the intent so that your `BroadcastReceiver will receive it`. As my answer stated, _you need a way for the user to launch your app manually_ at least once, so you should include an Activity that can be opened from the launcher.

Comment: I already have a MainActivity whereby it can be used to be launched manually once. So does that mean, the user just needs to launch the app manually once and after which ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED will be utilised for the auto launch?

Comment: That's what should happen, yes

Comment: and my coding is correct for this? but it still doesn't seem to happen correctly

Comment: I have read quite a bit of developer note and it is stating on the autolaunch of service instead of app. does it actually make a difference