# Android - BroadcastReceiver Not Triggering for BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am working with a Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime  that uses Android 5.0.2. What I want to do is simple, I want my application to boot up when the phone restarts. I am aware that to activate broadcasters I must run the application manually first after installing it. I do this and it still doesn't work. Here's my broadcaster code:

```
public class onStartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public onStartupReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("PLEASE", "System boot notification received.");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Log.e("PLEASE", "System boot notification received.");
        Intent i = new Intent(context,TestGPSBackgroundActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);

        }
    }
}
```

And here's my manifest relevant code:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">


    <activity
        android:name=".TestGPSBackgroundActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.jorge.gpsevixel.onStartupReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

I've been doing a lot of research that suggests removing the line android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" from the receiver and such, but no luck.

I've read things like [App doesn't auto-start an app when booting the device in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353411/app-doesnt-auto-start-an-app-when-booting-the-device-in-android) and a lot of similar questions/answers but none has helped me. Hope Anyone can help me I"m getting desperate.

Comment: is your app installed on external storage i mean sd card ?

Comment: It shouldn't, I am installing it directly on internal memory with the following line: android:installLocation="internalOnly"